# R Spark integration, Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: r, apache-spark, integration

```
sc.addFile(distScript)
val piped = rdd.pipe(Seq(SparkFiles.get("finddistance.R")),
        Map("SEPARATOR" -> ","))
**val result = piped.collect**
```

During call of `piped.collect`, error comes as not a valid win-32 application. While `R` is installed for 32 bit, with path added in environment variable.

Even able to run the R code through command line using command

```
Rscript xxx.R
```

Exact error coming is :-

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\gkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-89859197-b46a-415a-aa61-975845629bb6\userFiles-d86f1867-d200-4b69-bab0-4876b8e24428\finddistance.R": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: See the difference: command line you are executing rscript, from your code the R file directly. Surely it's not a valid Win32 application as the error says, so why not execute rscript?

Comment: Can you please give an example where can we put the R script.